# Need help to determine % difference between DNA-strand from two different haplotypes. Known nucleotide diversity and more

Tags: genetics, dna

Backround:
229 DNA sequences
493 bp in length 
Haplotype diversity: 0.9956
Average  number  of  nucleotide  differences: 12.50544
Polymorphic sites: 145
Nucleotide diversity: 0.02426

Is it possible to determine how many percent difference there is, on average, between DNA-strands from the different haplotypes?

The answer may be quite obvious, but this is new to me.

Comment: No, unless you have the distribution of haplotype frequencies. In that case you could compute the expected difference in nucleotide across haplotypes based on the average number of nucleotide difference conditioned on that H distribution.